# Make the plugin directory recognize new version numbers

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I updated readme.txt Stable Tag and tagged versions 0.2, 0.3 and latest 0.3.1 in SVN. After checkin, the new version is recognized only partly:

- On the dev-tab it links to the latest version (0.3.1) in the svn repository.
- The link-text still reads "0.1"
- The download button reads "Download Version 0.1"
- All other versions are listed under "other versions"

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/geouri/developers/

**Question**: How to make the directory recognize version 0.3.1 ?

Comment: Did you update the stable tag number in both `\trunk` and in `\tags\0.3.1`?

Comment: Yes, both are on `Stable tag: 0.3.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you update version numbers in all relevant locations:

- `\trunk`

  - `readme.txt`
  - `pluginfile.php`
- `\tags\{tag}`

  - `pluginfile.php`
  - (note: you *should* update `readme.txt`, but outside of trunk, it's only for aesthetics)

In this case, you updated `readme.txt` in `\trunk`, but you didn't update the Plugin file in [`\trunk`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/geouri/trunk/geouri.php) or in [`\tags\0.3.1`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/geouri/tags/0.3.1/geouri.php).