# Plugin version not updated with new version

Tags: plugin-development

I also checked [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110882/make-the-plugin-directory-recognize-new-version-numbers), and tested the `/trunk` and `/tags/1.1` readme.txt files stabletag are same.

```
/trunk/readme.txt
=== Plugin Name ===
Contributors: jogesh_pi
Tags: tags goes here
Requires at least: 3.6
Tested up to: 3.9.1
Stable tag: 1.1
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```

and in `tags/1.1/readme.txt`

```
=== Plugin Name ===
Contributors: jogesh_pi
Tags: tags goes here
Requires at least: 3.6
Tested up to: 3.9.1
Stable tag: 1.1
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
```

But still my plugin displayed the first version 1.0 with the functionality of 1.1 just the version not updated. Please tell me what i have missed or how do i make it correct?

[image]

### Steps

1. First i created a folder with the new version in `tags/` directory, i have already a directory in exists with the base version that is `tags/1.0`. I created a new `tags/1.1`
2. In my local system i have tested everything and its working fine. So i copied all the files in the `tags/1.1`
3. One mistake that i have done in my previous release with the `Stable Tag` was i mentioned that `Stable tag: 3.8` in my `tags/0.1` so i changed it in `tags/1.1` to `Stable tag: 1.1` and commit entire `tags/1.1`.
4. Next i copied all the files from `tags/1.1` and pasted in `trunk/` directory and again commit the `trunk/` directory that it.

I have doubt on `Stable tag: 3.8` of version in `tags/0.1` so i changed it to `Stable tag: 0.1` and commit the `tags/0.1` too. I don't know if its wrong or not :(

Comment: Can you mention the steps you followed to release the new version 1.1?

Comment: @Chittaranjan thanks for the reply, I have updated my question with the steps.

Comment: Did you change the version number in your main plugin file header?

Comment: @NickYoung AHH a big mistake by me :(, you are absolutely right i forget to add the version number in the main plugin files header. And now its working great :) Thanks you so much my friend.